# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when receive json

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

here is my code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/profile/add_jobs',
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    data: {json:JSON.stringify(all_publication)}, 
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('.all').html('');
 }});return false; //disable refresh
```

and the `all_publication` is an array containing values,

in controller I put this code:

```
public function add_jobs()
{
    echo ($_POST['json']);
    foreach ($_POST['json'] as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = array('name'=>$value['pub_name'],'details'=>$value['pub_details'],'date_time'=>$value['pub_date']);
    }
    $this->profile_model->insert_publication($data);
}
```

But appeared to me this message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

please show me a way for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify your array. Try:

```
data: {json : all_publication},
```

Comment: The same problem.. "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: What's the result when you do `print_r($_POST['json']);`?

Comment: when execute "echo $_POST['json']" the result in console is  array "{"0":{"pub_name":"name2","pub_domain":"{\"10\":\"Web\",\"26\":\"Formal Model\"}","pub_details":"details2","pub_date":"2015-05-27"},"1":{"pub_name":"name2","pub_domain":"{\"10\":\"Web\",\"26\":\"Formal Model\"}","pub_details":"details2","pub_date":"2015-05-27"}}"
but when i put "foreach"Shows me this message "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: When you echo an array in PHP the result is "Array". That means you're not passing an array at all. Perhaps it would help if you showed how all_publication is defined.

Comment: How can I receive the array in controller ,and get their content?

Answer (score 0):

Use **json_decode** with second parameter as true (for getting output as array) before passing it to foreach loop

So revised code looks like

```
public function add_jobs()
{
    echo ($_POST['json']);
    $postArray=json_decode($_POST['json'], true); // Decoding json to array
    foreach ($postArray as $key => $value) {
        $data[] = array('name'=>$value['pub_name'],'details'=>$value['pub_details'],'date_time'=>$value['pub_date']);
    }
    $this->profile_model->insert_publication($data);
}
```